# How to implement horizontal & vertical chain type concept in recyclerview gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

As always I have read through several posts on this topic across this site. If this truly is duplication I will delete this question. Majority of cases on here are dealing with orientation changes or looking to amend fixed values depending on the screensize. I am not worried about fixing width and height values.

What I want to achieve is a 6x10 grid which fills the screen no matter what size it is (orientation is fixed to portrait)

Here is my recyclerview item, I started with wrap content on the views and then tried match parent, neither makes any difference. On a small screen it fits fine and on a large screen it sits in the middle but is the same size.

I know I can't directly create a chain in my recyclerview item xml because I need to make a chain out of more than 1 view. I attempted to manually set the main layout with spread chain and a weight of 1 and then set the layout to 0dp, ran the code and obviously it didnt work

So, key question, is there a way to simply write the item xml so that it is dynamic or do we always have to create a subclass of sorts to generate different layouts per screensize?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/level_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_Level"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/sub_level_button_text_color" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/StarOutline"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="3"
            android:progressTint="@color/StarOutline"
            android:stepSize="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot on large screen]

To further assist with this here is my adapter

```
package com.maxcell.sumitup


import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RatingBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView



class LevelsAdaptor(private val onClick:(id:Int,mainLevel:Int,subLevel:Int,stars:Float,bonusGame:Boolean,type:Int)->Unit) : ListAdapter<Levels, LevelsAdaptor.LevelsViewHolder>(LevelsComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LevelsViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_storymode_items, parent, false)
        return LevelsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LevelsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(
            current.id,
            current.mainLevel,
            current.subLevel,
            current.stars,
            current.unlocked,
                current.bonusround,
                current.questiontype
        )
    }


    inner class LevelsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val TVLEVEL: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_Level)
        private val rating: RatingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)
        private val layoutBackground: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_background)
        private val myContext = itemView.context
        //private val myContext: Context = sumView.context
        fun bind(ID: Int, ML: Int, SL: Int, Stars: Float, Unlocked: Boolean,BonusRound:Boolean,QuestionType:Int) {
            TVLEVEL.text = ID.toString()
            rating.rating = Stars

            if (Unlocked){
                itemView.isEnabled=true;itemView.isClickable=true;layoutBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level_background)
            }else{
                itemView.isEnabled=false;itemView.isClickable=false;layoutBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.standard_background_deactivated);TVLEVEL.setTextColor(myContext.getColor(R.color.ColorOnDeactivated))
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                //Set your codes about intent here
                onClick(ID,ML,SL,Stars,BonusRound,QuestionType)
            }
        }

        }
    }

    class LevelsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Levels>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Levels, newItem: Levels): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Levels, newItem: Levels): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a recycler view, if there is only ever 6x10 views and they are all displayed on the screen at the same time?

Comment: I have 600 actually and only show the results from a specific stage/level. Upon changing level the recylcerview updates. I am limiting it to 60 each time but the data that fills the view varies by stage. Screenshot added to show how it looks on 10.1 screen

Comment: Okay I understand. So I believe your options would be to manually work out the width of each item (in `onBindViewHolder`)... not really a nice approach, or...

My preferred approach would be to make a single `RecyclerView` item actually be the entire 6x10 grid for the entire stage. So the recycler view would have 10 items in total, each representing one stage.

I don't think there would be any performance impact to doing it like this, since all 60 items displayed at once either way.

Comment: So there is definitely not a way for recyclerview views to be dynamically sized like we can with other views? My only issue with coding 60 views is what if later I suddenly have 100 sublevels (or more)? managing chains across such a large amount of views is definitely problematic as adding another view nearly always requires all constraints to be removed before linking them all back up again

Comment: What is the negative to your first option of getting size within the onbindviewholder? Also my views tend to be managed in levelviewholder rather than onbind so can I just confirm that its onbind where i should be getting and setting widths if i follow that approach?

Comment: Sure, just not in the XML layout. You could probably just take the view height/width from your fragment/activity and pass it as a constructor parameter to your adapter.

This in the `onCreateViewHolder` method, you can then just resize the root `view` to the correct value (divide by 10 or 6 etc).

Ideally you don't want to fetch the values in your adapt, you should fetch them in your activity/fragment and use them as a parameter of the adapter.

Comment: There is no real need to do it in `onBindViewHolder`... once the view is inflated in `onCreateViewHolder`, the size of the screen will not change (The only time the size will change is if they rotate the device... in which case the whole activity+adapter is destroyed and recreated anyway).

Comment: ok thanks @Greg I will research setting the width and height within the oncreateviewholder method and pass the measurements as parameter in the adapter constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `RecyclerView` width to `match_parent`, your `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `TextView` and `RatingBar` widths to `match_parent`, the items will stretch to fill the entire width of the screen (assuming you're using `GridLayoutManager`)

[image]

However, you'll notice that they don't fit the screen vertically, you have to scroll to them all. Setting height to 'match_parent' won't help here, you'll have to calculate the height in your adapter if you want them to fit exact.

This might make it look a bit strange on certain devices though (such as phones with longer screens).

[image]

To give a better looking layout, you might want to set the following properties on the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:1"
```

[image]

Comment: So after all this I had tried what you said above already with one BIG exception... My recyclerview was wrap content and all views in the item.xml were match parent. So the missing link was me not setting my recyclerview also to match parent. I dont mind them scrolling vertically. The width was the main issue. I will pass in the height if I feel it looks bad after further testing of different device sizes. Thank you for your time

Comment: app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:1" <- I have problems with this as it tells me 3:1 is not a correct float value?

Comment: No problem! I thought that might have been the case after re-reading (it shouldn't sit in the middle of the screen... it should try to expand).

Comment: Hmm are you setting it on your `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:1">

Comment: Ah I think they have changed the implementation. I think try setting it to 0.3.

Comment: I have tried various float values which do indeed resolve but the height remains at 0dp and therefore nothing shows when the recyclerview loads -     app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="0.5">

Comment: That's strange! So the height should be 0dp for the constraintDimensionRatio to work. It should accept ratios or floats, maybe try updating your libraries in gradle if it's a slightly older project? Oh and is your RecyclerView's height set to `match_parent`?

The full docs for it can be seen here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: Yeah this time the recyclerview was set correctly. I will keep on playing around. The main bit was the width. I can look at the height separately. Thanks again for your help